# Delete command not working on a SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
public void deleteEntity(int id ) {
         db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        try
           {
            db.beginTransaction();
            /*String s = "DELETE FROM entity_save WHERE _id=" + id;
            db.execSQL(s);*/
            int i=db.delete("entity_save", "save_id = ?", new String[]{ String.valueOf(id) });
           }
       catch(Exception e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        finally
          {
           db.endTransaction();
           db.close();}}
          }
```

Comment: what is your problem? your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `setTransactionSuccessful()` to actually commit and not roll back your changes on `endTransaction()`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, make this function in your SQLite Class and call this function where you want to perform delete operation. You have to just pass id to delete.

```
public void deleteRow(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + "='" + id + "'");
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Change your method like this:

```
 public void deleteEntity(int id ) { 
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        try{
            db.beginTransaction();
            int i=db.delete("entity_save", "save_id = " +"'"+id+"'",null });
        }catch(Exception e)
        {e.printStackTrace();}finally{
            db.endTransaction();
            db.close();}}
    }
```

Hope it solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
public void deleteEntity(int id ) {
     db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    int i=db.delete("entity_save", "save_id = ?", new String[]{ String.valueOf(id) });
}
```